# monaco-editor does not syntax highlight inside script tag of html file

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using react-monaco-editor in an application and I have noticed that it does not syntax-highlight javascript code inside a script tag of an html document. Does anyone know why?

[image: screenshot of editor]

I am using the monaco-editor-webpack-plugin and even though I define my own javascript grammar in my component, the html language support should be loaded by monaco.

Note: I can provide more code on the way I set my grammars if required. I do this because I have also written code to convert a vscode theme to a monaco-friendly version.

monaco-editor-webpack-plugin config:

```js
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
      languages: [
        'html',
        'markdown',
        'css',
        // 'javascript',
        // 'typescript',
        // 'json',
      ],
      features: ['!gotoSymbol'],
    }),
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mike, do you have any insight on this?

Comment: monaco-editor uses [this html plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-html) for HTML language support (which includes syntax highlighting). I don't know why embedded JS highlighting doesn't work for you, but check which tokens have been assigned to the text (via the command pallet: F1 -> Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes).

Comment: Thanks Mike! Using the token inspector I see that the script tag has a token of language: html, token type: other. The embedded js code has language: vs.editor.nullMode, token type: other. Do you think I could manually use the html plugin? I am using webpack and use the monaco-editor-webpack-plugin. I have edited my code to show this.

Comment: Your code is confusing: you don't enable JS in your webpack plugin and you register a JS provider with nothing in it, but just the id. I don't know if the HTML plugin uses the JS plugin if available, but I would think so. In any case, SO is not a discussion forum, [but a Q&A site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so we should stop disscussing here.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyways.

Comment: Try to uncomment those languages, disable your own JS specification, and try again. Monaco uses workers to parse, lint, autocomplete, etc. as users type. The HTML language uses the embedded `text/javascript` language which, most probably, is being handled by the JS/TS worker.

Comment: Thanks @Ben. I have those lines commented out because I actually want to register my own grammars and set a custom theme that a create by converting vscode themes to monaco friendly themes. I appreciate the insight though, maybe I need to find a way to register the embedded text/javascript language. If you have time, I have a full code sample with the issue I created here: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2350